# Quota sampling in R

Tags: r, weights, survey-sampling

I was provided surveys with quotas set at the provincial, gender, and employment status levels. I was wondering if it is possible to use `survey` package in `R` to perform raking and get the appropriate weights to make my sample more representative?

I am an economist with very limited experience with the survey literature: I am not sure if it makes sense to do the above since I am using a non-probability sample method. Could someone point me in the right direction for some literature on how to handle Quota web surveys?

Comment: Are you asking for R code, or general advice on doing this? If about R, this would be off-topic in here.

Comment: To be honest, both. That said, I can for the specific on how to work on quota surveys in `R` on StackOverflow. But I would love some help with how to handle quota samples, especially on how to make them more representative when there is oversampling of some groups.

Answer (score 1):

Chiming in a bit late here, but I can provide some advice that may be useful. I've found that there's not much documentation and/or easy examples re: quota sampling (using `R`), so I went ahead and created my own method utilizing the `survey` library. For the sake of sharing my method without explicitly posting code, I've summarized the general process below.

Randomized quota sampling using survey weights as probabilities:

1. Generate weights using the `rake` function
2. Randomly sample from that set, using those weights as sampling probabilities. I've generally found that taking a 90% sample is a good starting point.
3. Iterate steps 1-2 until your desired `n` is reached.
4. If you want to optimize your sample for best match regardless of size, you'll want to measure how closely your sample matches your set quotas after each iteration, then pick the sample with the best match. I've found that mean absolute error/deviation works generally well for this purpose.

I'm sure there are libraries out there that can do this for you (perhaps `sampling`?), but clear examples are hard to come by in their documentation.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for this method? It seems very strange and I'm not sure what it's supposed to achieve. What's the point of step 2? Why would you entirely discard observations?

Answer (score 0):

#### Introductory resource for raking with non-probability samples

Quota sampling is just one form of non-probability sampling, and there is a large, active literature on estimation from non-probability samples.

Pew Research recently produced a good, fairly non-technical overview of weighting methods for non-probability web surveys:

https://www.pewresearch.org/methods/2018/01/26/how-different-weighting-methods-work/

This is part of an interesting evaluation study of the effectiveness of such adjustments:

https://www.pewresearch.org/methods/2018/01/26/how-different-weighting-methods-work/

#### Software options

There are a couple good options for this:

- The `survey` package has a function `rake()`, documented here:
  https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/survey/versions/4.1-1/topics/rake
- The `pewmethods` R package has a raking function, and an example of its usage is located here:
  https://medium.com/pew-research-center-decoded/weighting-survey-data-with-the-pewmethods-r-package-d040afb0d2c2